# echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online Write error

Tags: linux, kernel, sys

I'm using the kernel

```
uname -r
5.8.13-050813-generic
```

In latest version due to 'CPU HOTPLUG' 2 CPU's are online and other 2 are offline

```
nproc  2

lscpu
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Off-line CPU(s) list:            2,3
```

I tried

```
sudo su
root: sudo echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online
```

But Im still getting this error

```
bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

could anyone help

Comment: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online is a status file, you are not supposed to update it.

Comment: As I searched online for updating the cpu's from offline state to online state I got this as an answer. Could you please suggest a way to make the other 2 cpu's online ?

Comment: Can you try `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online` ?

Comment: That didn't worked
`tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online: Operation not permitted`